# Where are all of the different Python Copies Installed?

Tags: homebrew, python

How can I find *all* of the different Python(s) installed on my Mac? I've accidentally damaged a copy of `Python 3` that was under `/usr/local/bin`, and want to replace it/fix it, but I don't even know how `Python 3` got there in the first place – macOS only ships with `2.7`.

Can I use HomeBrew to fix a broken copy?

How can I clean up my Python copies, so that I just have what should be there?

Comment: You ask for conflicting things " I just have what should be there" and Homebrew. Homebrew does not touch system things

Comment: Because I’m talking about all of the python installations I have

Answer (score 1):

You can re-install the python3 that you messed up. With `brew install python3`  This linked question talks about the command line tools that may be need to complete the install. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583427/brew-install-python3-fails

To remove the home-brew versions, so that you only have the system original 
`brew remove python python3  && brew cleanup`

Comment: That installs a home brew copy, and doesn’t replace the system one

Comment: /usr/local/non does not contain any system things it is empty on a clean macOS install

Comment: You said "can I use HomeBrew to fix".  "Just have what should be there" is ambiguous, do you mean an old-outdated by standard osX system pre-installed version of python.  Or a working, shiny-brand new version?

Comment: I just want to fix the one in /usr/local. I accidentally broke it by deleting one of the files. I was wondering if I could change the directory of homebrew’s install to place into the system version.

Comment: Check the /us/local one by `cd /usr/local && open .` In Finder right-click get-info on python. You see that it is aliased to `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/python3.6.1 . . . `. That is the home-brew version that you deleted the file from.  "Fix" it with `brew reinstall python3`  Does `which python` point to /usr/bin/python. and you want `/usr/local/bin/python3` to be the default instead?  Then your problem is actually that /usr/bin is before /usr/local/bin in your `echo $PATH` you need to read up on changing the order of your PATH.